# How to aggregate data in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a distributed system on 3 nodes and my data is distributed among those nodes. For example, I have a `test.csv` file which exists on all 3 nodes, and it contains 4 columns of

```
row   | id,  C1, C2,  C3
----------------------
row1  | A1 , c1 , c2 ,2
row2  | A1 , c1 , c2 ,1 
row3  | A1 , c11, c2 ,1 
row4  | A2 , c1 , c2 ,1 
row5  | A2 , c1 , c2 ,1 
row6  | A2 , c11, c2 ,1 
row7  | A2 , c11, c21,1 
row8  | A3 , c1 , c2 ,1
row9  | A3 , c1 , c2 ,2
row10 | A4 , c1 , c2 ,1
```

I want try aggregating the above result set. How can I aggregate the data set by the `id`, `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` columns and output it like this?

```
row   | id,  C1, C2,  C3
----------------------
row1  | A1 , c1 , c2 ,3
row2  | A1 , c11, c2 ,1 
row3  | A2 , c1 , c2 ,2 
row4  | A2 , c11, c2 ,1 
row5  | A2 , c11, c21,1 
row6  | A3 , c1 , c2 ,3
row7  | A4 , c1 , c2 ,1
```

I tried the following:

```
from array import array 
from datetime import datetime 
import pyspark.sql 
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext, StructField, StringType,  IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), False),
    StructField("C1", StringType(), False), 
    StructField("C2", StringType(), False),
    StructField("C3", IntegerType(), False)])
base_rdd = sc.textFile("/home/hduser/spark-1.1.0/Data/test.tsv").map(lambda l: 

l.split(",")

rdd = base_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(id = x[0], C1 = x[1], C2 = x[2], C3 = int(x[3])))
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
srdd = sqlContext.inferSchema(rdd)
```

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you can do following steps. I don't know the python steps, below are java steps. I hope you could relate it to python.

1. read the csv file

`JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile(args[0]);`

2. create a pair rdd from the file

   `JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> pairMap = input.mapToPair(
                   new PairFunction<String, Integer, String>() {
               @Override
               public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String line) throws Exception {
                   String[] s = line.split(",");
                   String key = s[0]+'#'+s[1]+'#' +s[2];// id,c1,c2
                   Integer value = Integer.valueOf(s[3]) //c3

                   return new Tuple2<Integer,String>(key, value);
               }
           });`
3. reduce the map by key

`JavaPairRDD<String,Integer>    result = pairMap.reduceByKey(
              new   Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
                        return v1+v2;
                    }
                });`

4. `result` object contains your expected result where key is `id+'#'+c1+'#'+c2` and value is aggregated `c3`. You can use this map further as you want. You could tokenize the key on `#` to get back your columns and could insert into a table using apache-spark-sql.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest to use 'com.databricks.spark.csv' for reading csv files (you need to load it using '--package' when you run pyspark shell http://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-csv). Then use groupBy method:

```
df = (sqlContext.read
  .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load("<your_file>.csv"))

df2= df.groupBy('id', 'C1', 'C2').agg({'C3': 'sum'}).sort('id', 'C1')

df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| id| C1| C2| C3|
+---+---+---+---+
| A1| c1| c2|  2|
| A1| c1| c2|  1|
| A1|c11| c2|  1|
| A2| c1| c2|  1|
| A2| c1| c2|  1|
| A2|c11| c2|  1|
| A2|c11|c21|  1|
| A3| c1| c2|  1|
| A3| c1| c2|  2|
| A4| c1| c2|  1|
+---+---+---+---+

df2.show()

+---+---+---+-------+
| id| C1| C2|sum(C3)|
+---+---+---+-------+
| A1| c1| c2|      3|
| A1|c11| c2|      1|
| A2| c1| c2|      2|
| A2|c11| c2|      1|
| A2|c11|c21|      1|
| A3| c1| c2|      3|
| A4| c1| c2|      1|
+---+---+---+-------+
```

If label 'row' is important you can add it later and rename 'sum(C3)' to 'C3'. For more information look at Spark Python API https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame